# Mongoose - Why my validator method failing?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my mongoose schema. I have validator function. When I print the length then it shows undefined. I want phno field to be 10 digits.Help!!

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

function validator (v) {
    console.log("phno len:"+v.length)
  return v.length == 10;
};

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fname:{type:String, required:true},
    lname:{type:String, required:true},
    username:{type:String, required:true},
    password:{type:String, required:true},
    phno:{type:Number,required:true,validate:[validator,'Phno must be 10 digits']},
    email:{type:String, required:true},
    dob:{type:Date,required:true},
    address:{type:String, required:true}
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `phno` is `Number`, there is no `length` in `Number`. `Numbers` have `min` and `max` validators.

Maybe you could change the `phno` type to `String`, it could meet your requirement to check the digits length.

Or try to convert number to string as below.

```
function validator (v) {
    console.log("phno len:" + v.toString().length)
    return v.toString().length == 10;
};
```